# How change a color of a table cell

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table in my site and I want to change a color of a single cell on each line, just like in the image: [image]

That's my code on html so far

```
       <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;" colspan="29">DESTINO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let val of table_headers">{{val}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let val of array">
            <td *ngFor="let item of val">{{item}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using Angular *ngFor directives. you can keep track of the indices and add a class to all cells that are on the diagonal.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let val of array; let i = index">
    <td *ngFor="let item of val; let j = index" [class.coloured]="i === j">{{item}}</td>
</tr>
```

```css
.coloured {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Man that worked perfectly thanks, but could you give me another help ?? I need to color the cell to the right of the one that is coloring now, it is coloring a cell before what I really need, I tried to put a let i = index + 1 for example but didn't work like that

Comment: Edit the condition like so:
`<tr *ngFor="let val of array; let i = index">
    <td *ngFor="let item of val; let j = index" [class.coloured]="i === j-1">{{item}}</td>
</tr>`

Comment: Man thanks a lot, I tried a lot of things here, but not that one, thanks man

Answer (score 1):

this code example will give you an idea.

```
function filterOddNumbers(integers){
      let oddOne = integers.filter((item) => Math.abs(item) % 2 === 1);
      let odderOne = integers.filter((item) => Math.abs(item) % 2 === 0);
    if (oddOne.length > 1) {
      return odderOne[0];
    }
    else {
      return oddOne[0];
    }
    }

  filterOddNumbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
```